# How to send several async requests at the same time using suspense vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm using `<Suspense>` and I have several requests in my child component with `await`:

```
await store.dispatch("product/getProduct", route.params.id).then(res => productData.value = res);
await store.dispatch("product/getCharacteristics", route.params.id).then(res => characteristicList.value = res);
await store.dispatch("price/getPrices", route.params.id).then(res => delivery.value = res);
```

So they run **one by one**, but I need them to run **at the same time**

My solution: I replaced `await` with `const request = ...`

And now I have only one `await`:

```
await Promise.all([request1, request2, request3, request4, request5, request6, request7]);
```

**Is it good practice? Or is there a better and more elegant way to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is what `Promise.all()` is for and it is very good practice. You should use it whenever possible to keep wait time low.

Some people (who are not me) generally prefer [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled). It does not reject when one of the inner promises fails, which allows for more refined error handling, but you have to unwrap the returned objects.